# Form Element Not Working On XMLHttpRequest Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to create a form which when clicked makes an XMLHttpRequest and writes information on the page.

Here's the HTML code.

```
<form>
<input id="myStock" type="text"/>
<input id="iSubmit" type="submit" value="Show Me Data"/>
<input type="reset" value="Reset Me" />
</form>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Here's the JS code:

```
var isubmit = document.getElementsByTagName("form")
[0].querySelector('input[type="submit"]');
isubmit.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
function myFunction() {
//some code here
 }
 var mystock = document.getElementsByTagName("form")
 [0].querySelector('input[type="text"]').value.trim();
 var urlext = mystock;
 urlext += 
 "&reportType=is&period=12&dataType=A&order=asc&columnYear=5&number=3";
  var url = "https://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/ReportProcess4CSV.html?
  t=";
 alert(url + urlext);
 xhttp.open("GET", url + urlext, true);
 xhttp.send();
 }
```

The problem is, when I am deleting the `<form>` tag on the HTML page and deleting the `getElementsByTagName("form")[0]` on the JS code, it's working fine.

However, with the form element intact, it's not returning any information.

Please help.

Comment: You neglected to prevent the default form submission - so the browser loads a “new page” instead of executing your AJAX request.

Comment: where is `xhttp` declared?

Comment: @CBroe - that could be part of `//some code here` :p

Comment: Some Pre declaration you need to show for identify exact problem

Comment: code for myFunction need to be share !

Comment: @CBroe thanks, that solved it for me.

Comment: @JaromandaX I had xhttp declared inside the code. It's working now. One question, is the url part correct? I mean, I am really unclear on the encodeURI and encodeURIcomponent things. Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem it's the input submit like @CBroe pointed out. You can prevent using the `e.preventDefault();`.

Or you can use do this:

```js
$('#iSubmit1').on('click', function(){
var value = $("#myStock").val();
$( "#demo" ).append( '<p>'+value+'</p>' );
});
  
    

$('#reset1').on('click', function(){
$( "p" ).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input id="myStock" type="text"/>
<button id = "iSubmit1" type="button">Show Me Data!</button> 
<button id = "reset1" type="button">Reset Me!</button> 
</form>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3h97gcco/) I made. I dont know if it helps you out though.

```
     $.POST( url+urltext, function( data ) {
 $('#demo').html(data);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but didn't get what you are trying to do with that script? Are you posting data to that URL?